# In PHP, what is the most efficient way to match a string against a list of keywords?

Tags: php, regex, string, match

I have a list of keywords, and need to check whether any of these occurs in a string. E.g.:

```
/* Keywords */
Rock
Paper
Scissors

/* Strings */
"This town rocks!"    /* Match */
"Paper is patient"    /* Match */
"Hello, world!"       /* No match */
```

I could put my keywords in an array, loop through it and do a preg_match() or substr() on each iteration, but that seems a bit cpu-expensive. I've mucked aroud with regexps a bit, but without much success.

What is the most efficient way (in terms of lean code and low CPU loads) to do this?

Note that the comparison must be case-insensitive.

Comment: Use a regex trie `(?i)(?:rock|paper|scissors)` This first level trie is `[psr]` If you have a bunch of keywords (like a couple of thousand), use a utility to convert them into a multi-level trie. http://www.regexformat.com

Comment: You say "that seems a bit cpu-expensive", but have you tried any of them?  If you want to know how long things take, then the best way to know is to actually try them.  You can also use packages like xdebug: http://xdebug.org/

Answer (score 3):

A regex with all alternatives will ensure string is scanned once, rather than N times for N keywords. PCRE library is very well optimized.

```
preg_match('/rock|paper|scissors/i', $string);
```

It gets faster if your keywords have common prefixes and you take advantage of that (essentially by building a trie and inlining it):

```
preg_match('/rock|paper|sci(?:ssors|ence)/i', $string);
```

And finally there's

```
preg_grep($regex, $array_of_strings);
```

that will match against an array of strings and return ones that match.

Answer (score 1):

Just to see if any keyword is found you could do this with keywords as an array:

```
if(str_ireplace($keyword_array, '', $string) != $string) {
    //match
} else {
    //no match
}
```

Comment: str_ireplace will scan the string N times for N keywords and will allocate memory for the new string. Quite bad performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know your keywords in advance, and you have multiple strings you wish to search through, you can implode your keywords to a regex and grep the strings:

```
$keywords = array ('Rock', 'Paper', 'sciSSors');
$strings  = array (
    "This town rocks!",
    "Hello, world!",
    "Paper is patient",
);

$rc = preg_grep(
    sprintf('/%s/i', implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $keywords))),
    $strings
);

/**
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "This town rocks!"
  [2]=>
  string(16) "Paper is patient"
}
*/
```

[See it here.](http://3v4l.org/TBWbJ)

Comment: This isn't quite bullet-proof: if your keywords contain a "/", you won't get what you expect.  Left as an exercise for the reader.